# How to resolve the issue for displaying the dynamic field on the corresponding bot

Tags: c#, botframework

I am working bot framework technology, in one of my project I want to set the dynamic field for that I had wrote below lines of code.

```
.Field(new FieldReflector<Customer>("Savings_Balance")
.SetType(null)
.SetActive((state) => state.Option == Options.SavingsAccountBalance)
.SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
    {
        if (state.Savings_Balance != null)
         {
            if (state.Savings_Balance.AccountNumber != null && state.Savings_Balance.PIN != null)
            {
                string availableBalance = SQLDatabaseService.checkingAccountBalance(state.Savings_Balance.AccountNumber, state.Savings_Balance.PIN);
                if (availableBalance != null && availableBalance != "")
                {
                    var totalsavingsbalance = new PromptAttribute($"Total available savings account balance is ${availableBalance:F2}");                          


                    field.SetPrompt(totalsavingsbalance);

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    field.SetPrompt(new PromptAttribute($"I'm sorry. I didn't understand you."));
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                field.SetPrompt(new PromptAttribute($"I'm sorry. I didn't understand you."));
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            field.SetPrompt(new PromptAttribute($"I'm sorry. I didn't understand you."));
            return false;
        }
     }))

var totalsavingsbalance = new PromptAttribute($"Total available savings account balance is ${availableBalance:F2}");                          
field.SetPrompt(totalsavingsbalance);
```

In the old version of bot, the above field will displayed successfully. But when I was updated to version 3 it’s not showing any field even the above line executing properly without any exceptions.
Please tell me what is problem and how can I resolve it.

Regards,

Pradeep

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "it's not showing any field"?

Comment: In the above code, I wrote the message in field.SetPrompt(new PromptAttribute($"Total available savings account balance is ${availableBalance:F2}"););

the above will not displayed like "Total available saving account balance is $2000".